# different error documents for different hosts listening on the same port

Tags: apache2

I have an apache2 with this similar configuration

```
<VirtualHost IP:8080>
        ServerName IP:8080
        DocumentRoot /var/www/x1
        ErrorDocument 400 https://IP:8080
        SSLEngine on
        ....
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost example.com:8080>
        ServerName example.com:8080
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
        ErrorDocument 400 https://example.com:8080
        SSLEngine on
        ....
</VirtualHost>
```

the problem is that when I access http:/example.com:8080 the error document that redirect is the one of the ip. 
What could be wrong?

I have try to put it inside the Directory directive but doesn't work either.

Comment: Hi zafete,

Welcome to StackOverflow! But I must say that your question is not really suited to Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is geared toward [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question is about server configuration. It would be more appropriate on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: ok thanks for the advice!